# SingleDatePicker by react-dates is not closing on change

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

Hey I have set up a react dates functionality on my app, however the date, when chosen doesnt make the calendar close.

I have the example here on https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dubinsky-xuxkj?file=/src/App.js:0-681

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SingleDatePicker } from "react-dates";
import "react-dates/initialize";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";

const CreateGroupEvent = (props) => {
  const [dob, setDob] = useState(null);
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const setDate = (date) => {
    setDob(date);
    setFocused(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SingleDatePicker
        date={dob}
        // {...input}
        onOutsideClick={true}
        numberOfMonths={1}
        onDateChange={setDate}
        focused={focused}
        onFocusChange={setFocused}
        id="dob"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default CreateGroupEvent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** EDITED : [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-silence-jwjuw?file=/src/App.js) is my example code sandbox.

How about trying this?

According to its [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dates#singledatepicker), `onFocusChange` seems to should take `{ focused : boolean }` objects as parameters.

```js
const onFocusChange = ({ focused }) => {
  setFocused(focused);
};
```

```js
<SingleDatePicker
    date={dob}
    onOutsideClick={true}
    numberOfMonths={1}
    onDateChange={setDate}
    focused={focused}
    onFocusChange={onFocusChange}
    id="dob"
  />
```

Comment: That doesnt, work, my setState function of setFocused does that anyways...

Comment: @Eddsters It works well when I try. check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-silence-jwjuw?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Hey you are right, i think the problem was that the input should have been typecasted as an object `({ focused })` like so, thank you so much!! Apologies for not catching that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a version related quirk -- if you just do:

```
onFocusChange={(focusedInput)=> setFocused(focusedInput.focus)}
```

it'll work.